# I am getting this error after running "$ rails server" command osx maverick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

```
[2014-08-01 11:40:40] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-08-01 11:40:40] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-05-14) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]
[2014-08-01 11:40:40] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
Exiting
```

Comment: please don't count enter code here line

Comment: Hi Joy, you can edit your question to fix stuff up :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've already got a server running on that port. try running it with a new port number eg `rails server --port 3001` or finding the other running server and killing it first

Comment: Hi Taryn, thanks for this code, I am learning from scratch and this mean a lot for me... once again thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute you server on port 3000, just do this:

you can find the ports your mac is listen on executing this command in terminal:

```
sudo  lsof -i :3000
```

with the pid in hand you can kill the process. Just pick the number in the pid column and then execute this command in the terminal:

```
sudo kill -9 <pid value>
```

and now you can execute rails server without trouble.

Comment: Thaks sergio, this command worked for me, however I haven't checked server is running or not? but thanks for wonderful suggestion

Comment: @JayPatel i`m not sure if i understand your question... do you wan't to know if with this commands we are checking if the server is running?